# Short story (possibly a novella) about people living in caves; women start giving birth to worms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

In eleventh grade, we read many a short story, sometimes novellas if our teacher liked them enough. I remember reading The Most Dangerous Game. This one short story I have been trying to find for nearly five years had to do with humans who lived in caves and all of a sudden the women started giving birth to worms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! When were you in eleventh grade? You could be a 17-year-old human or a 350,000-year-old zombie and we wouldn’t know :P

Comment: See [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help improving your question, too. I hope this is found, it sounds crazy!

Comment: A 350,000-year-old cave person worm zombie, even.

Comment: Not that it matters, but usually, "The Most Dangerous Game" is read in ninth grade.